# Can this integral similar to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ be evaluated?

Tags: definite-integrals

I know that the integral  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = \pi$.

Just for fun, I thought if it would be possible evaluate the same integral but only consider the area below the curve and above the x-axis? Approximately would be fine, if an exact expression is not available.

To make this precise one could define the integral as $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \mu_0(\frac{\sin(x)}{x})dx $$

where $\mu_0(x)$ is the unit step function such that

$x<0 \implies \mu_0(x) = 0$

and $x \geq 0 \implies \mu_0(x) = 1$

Comment: Alternatively, setting $f:=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ you could express it as 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)+|f(x)|}{2}\ dx,$$
and so the problem is the same as determining $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|\ dx$.

Comment: And $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx $$ is blatantly divergent.

Comment: So the integral doesn't even converge?

Comment: @Adam: so it seems. By integration by parts $$\int_{0}^{N}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx \sim\frac{2}{\pi}\log N.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral will diverge. Without doing the math in detail, each positive section between 2n*pi and (2n+1)*pi will integrate to k/n, for k=2 in the limit as n increases. So the integral on the positive side will be approximately the sum (n=1 to infinity) of 2/n . Which is divergent. (same on the -ve side).